# 'TextCtrl' object has no attribute 'Value'

Tags: python

I am learning to pogram with python and 
I am interested in creating a GUI by using the wxGlade.

I've created a simple application which add 2 values entered by the user.

user will enter the first value into a text box called `text_ctrl_1` and the second value into the second text box called `text_ctrl_2`

by clicking the add button, the application will add the values and show it on another button.

below is the code defining the function of the add button

```
def sum(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    c = self.text_ctrl_1.Value + self.text_ctrl_2.Value
    self.button_2.SetLabel(c)
    event.Skip()
```

my problem is that after entering value to both of the text box, when i click on the add button, 
python told me that there is an attribute error : 'TextCtrl' object has no attribute 'Value'

still a newbies in programming

thanks alot for the help

Comment: try [GetValue](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html#GetValue) ?

Comment: there is another error that came out, TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for+: 'instancemethod' and 'instancemethod'

Comment: yeah you want to call the method like this `GetValue()`

Comment: thank you very much. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [GetValue](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html#GetValue) method on the `TextCtrl` class, like so:

```
def sum(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    c = self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue() + self.text_ctrl_2.GetValue()
    self.button_2.SetLabel(c)
    event.Skip()
```